# Hover e Disabled ao mesmo tempo

Tags: html, css

Tenho 2 botões. Um eu quero que esteja desabilitado e o outro esteja com efeito hover. Quando faço desta forma abaixo os dois botões ficam com efeito hover.

Como faço para que o botão que está desabilitado não tenha nenhum efeito?

```css
.btn-destaque{
    padding: 25px 15px 25px 15px;
    background-color: #7857a5;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #8c37ff;
}
.btn-destaque:disabled{
    background-color: #b3a4c7;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border: 1px solid #b3a4c7;
}
.btn-destaque:hover{
    background-color: #8c37ff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-destaque disabled" disabled="disabled">Teste</button>
<button type="button" class="btn-destaque">Teste</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar o [`not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) para aplicar o hover somente em elementos que possuem a classe `.btn-destaque` que não tenham o atributo `disabled`:

```css
.btn-destaque {
  padding: 25px 15px 25px 15px;
  background-color: #7857a5;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #8c37ff;
}

.btn-destaque:disabled {
  background-color: #b3a4c7;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  border: 1px solid #b3a4c7;
}

.btn-destaque:not([disabled]):hover {
  background-color: #8c37ff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-destaque disabled" disabled="disabled">Teste</button>
<button type="button" class="btn-destaque">Teste</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o `:not(:disabled)` no CSS.

```css
.btn-destaque {
    padding: 25px 15px 25px 15px;
    background-color: #7857a5;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #8c37ff;
}

.btn-destaque:disabled {
    background-color: #b3a4c7;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border: 1px solid #b3a4c7;
}

.btn-destaque:not(:disabled):hover {
    background-color: #8c37ff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-destaque disabled" disabled="disabled">Teste</button>
<button type="button" class="btn-destaque">Teste</button>
```